# how to call azure to get resource for classic (ASM) storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-rest-api

We have some ARM as well as some legacy Azure ASM resources and I have a need to query azure endpoints for info on both the ARM and the classic storage resources.  I can query the  ARM just fine, but when I try to query the classic via the same url, I get no data.

ARM attempt url:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/abcdef-123456/resourceGroups/MyEastResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts
/myazureresourcename?api-version=2015-08-19
```

Attempted classic (ASM) url:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/abcdef-123456/resourceGroups/MyEastResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts/myazureresourcename?api-version=2015-08-19
```

Comment: Can you try with `2016-11-01` API version instead of `2015-08-19`?

Answer (score 1):

> api-version=2015-08-19

Looks like the API Version, you are using is not valid when we have tried to get the properties of the storage account using postman & request got failed with the below error.

[image]

We have tested this in our local environment it is working fine, Below statements are based on the analysis.

In our local environment, Using postman & Azure Management Rest API's. We are able to get the properties of the classic storage account.

Below are the list of api versions supported by the classic storage account's:

- 2016-11-01
- 2016-04-01
- 2015-12-01
- 2015-06-01
- 2014-06-01
- 2014-04-01-beta
- 2014-04-01
- 2014-01-01

**Here is the sample output for reference :**

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I will try those. I was able to get a positive response confirming the resource's existence using the following url, which does use a newer version of the api:

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{mysubscriptionid}/resourceGroups{myresourcegroupname}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts/{myclassicresourcename}/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?interval=PT1H&aggregation=Average&metricNamespace=Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts&api-version=2021-05-01&metricnames=Availability,SuccessE2ELatency,SuccessServerLatency,Transactions,Egress,Ingress,UsedCapacity